# How to modify a jquery plugin default properties inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, javascript-objects, slick.js

I am working with slick slider jquery plugin. I have created a global method for slick slider
**"a.js"**

```
var KOUKIDefaultScripts=function(){

slickSlider: function( $container, $options={}  ){

   this.sliderFunc = jQuery( $container ).slick();
  }
}():
```

Inside another js file I have written

**b.js**

```
var courseSlider = new KOUKIDefaultScripts.slickSlider('#courseSlider',{
    dots : true,
    arrows : false
  });
```

I have to edit my `slickSlider` code so that all the properties that I have declared inside the b.js gets attached to the slick object which I am unable to do.

In my console I can see the $options object, but I am unable to attach those properties in the slick slider so that it works.

Can anybody say what I am missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't understand why "but I am unable to attach those properties in the slick slider so that it works". What code are you using to attach properties? Any more detail?

Comment: I found my error. It is working now. Thanks @blackmiaool for your response

Comment: Can you explain what is your solution? It could be that can it help others!

Answer (score 0):

**"a.js"**

```
 var KOUKIDefaultScripts=function(){
    return{
      slickSlider: function( $container, $options ){

           this.sliderFunc = jQuery( $container ).slick( $options );
          }
    }
     }():
```

**"b.js"**

```
var courseSlider = new KOUKIDefaultScripts.slickSlider('#courseSlider',{
    dots : true,
    arrows : true,
    autoplay:true,

  });
```

It worked